# get first and last value form a mysql results array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, max, min

How would you go about getting the first and last value from a sql query . 
I want the highest and lowest vaue of variable $integer1, so I have ordered them in Ascending order in my sql query, but now need to pull them out of the array as first and last items. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
$first = reset($result);
$last = end($result);
```

Also, In the sql query I select string1, string2 and integer1

I want to order by integer1 and then print out first and last (both strings)

```
 First   echo $string 1. " " . /4string2;
 Last   echo $string 1. " " . /4string2;
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` output?

Comment: Do you need a MIN and MAX value of one field or the complete row of data?

Comment: i need MIN and MAX of one field, but like to output the name (which is a different field) of who got the min and max too.

Comment: var dump returns "resource(5) of type (mysql result) "

Answer (score 3):

Asuming you want the min and the max value of a field in SQL.

Instead of fetching all the rows from your table and take the first and the last row in PHP, do it in SQL !

```
SELECT MIN(your_field), MAX(your_field) FROM your_table WHERE conditions GROUP BY field1,field2
```

Comment: I've edited my question, could I use that to also select the strings?

Answer (score 2):

array_shift give you the first row, array_pop the last one

```
$first = array_shift($rows) ;
$last = array_pop($rows) ;
```

Comment: I have edited my question, 

and thent ried to adapt your answer to :
$first = array_shift($result['string1']) ;

but still not working

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of code ? What your result contains and where does it come from ? Maybe you should look at $first_row = array_shift($rows) ; $first_string = $first_row['string1'] ; but without result content difficult to say.

Comment: the results would contain the following several times, however i only want the record that has the higest and lowest integer, and print their two strings.  ---------------------

string1,string2,integer ---------------------- does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use array_shift and array_pop methods
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php